# Hosting WCF service on IIS (The resource cannot be found)

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am making WFC service. When I debug it from Visual Studio all is ok, but I've faced with problem when I deploy it on real IIS.

After deploying I still can get WSDL but when I request WebGet method (which returns a simple XML document) method I got the following error:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

What can be cause of problem?

My Web.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="XXXX.TSDX.UI.TsdxService">
    <endpoint 
        address="Tsdx" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="TestBinding" 
        behaviorConfiguration="RESTFriendly" 
        contract="XXXX.TSDX.UI.ITsdxService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TestBinding" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTFriendly">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the correct version of the .NET framework selected in the ASP.NET tab (in IIS) for your application

Comment: Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1 - it seems that it's correct

Comment: Check the properties of your project, your must be sure that the version match

Comment: Checked - Yes, it's match. :-/

Comment: Verify that your client and service file match (Adress section of WCF)

Comment: I am tring to use the browser as client. It's REST service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting this service in MVC app please make sure to add below line to ignore controller routing conflict, I had this issue after struggling for sometime I found this answer which has resolved the issue.

routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*.svc(/.*)?" });