# Hosting WFC service on different IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

It's about my yesterday's [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178111/hosting-wcf-service-on-iis-the-resource-cannot-be-found/11178254)

Now I deployed this service on two identical IIS on two different PC. And this service works fine on IIS on my PC and doesn't work on other:

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for...
```

The same code, the same assemblies, the same Web.config files. And I cannot find out a difference between these IIS.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. The problem was that I developed MVC3 web site together with WCF service in the same application, and I have to add the following code in order to solve this problem:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
```

I hope it helps somebody who will use WFC and MVC in the same application.